# Replace defined string if condition X applies

Tags: php

I have the following php line:

```
define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname);
```

which displays the name of a city (for example: `"Rome"`).

If `originalCityname` is or ends with `"Rome"`, I'd like to add `" (Italy)"` so it will display `"Rome (Italy)"` and not just `"Rome"`.

How can I achieve this in php?

#### EDIT

Thank you all guys! What about if "Rome" is part of the string? For example "Name of a Town - Rome" changed to "Name of a Town - Rome (Italy)"? Can I add " (Italy)" if the value ENDS with "Rome"? Thanks again!

Comment: What, like `if($city->originalCityName === "Rome") $city->originalCityName .= " (Italy)";`?

Comment: Thank you all guys! What about if "Rome" is part of the string? For example "Name of a Town - Rome" changed to "Name of a Town - Rome (Italy)"? Can I add " (Italy)" if the value ENDS with "Rome"? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change a constant after you have defined it.
So you have to set the value once:

```
if($city->originalCityname == "Rome") {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname)." (Italy)";
} else {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname);
}
```

---

EDIT: If you need to check if the value ends with "Rome" just use:

```
if(substr($city->originalCityname, -4) == "Rome") {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname)." (Italy)";
} else {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname);
}
```

---

EDIT: If you need to check if the value ends with "Rome" or "Milan" (to add Italy) or "London" (to add United Kingdom) just use:

```
if(substr($city->originalCityname, -4) == "Rome" or substr($city->originalCityname, -5) == "Milan") {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname)." (Italy)";
} elseif(substr($city->originalCityname, -6) == "London") {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname)." (United Kingdom)";
} else {
    define("CITY_NAME", $city->originalCityname);
}
```

---

Before you ask for further variations please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/language.control-structures.php).

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the question to be more precise, could you please help me once again? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working perfectly! What about if I'd like to make the following: if Rome and Milan then " (Italy)" and if London then " (United Kingdom)"? I am sorry if I am making double questions. If I need to start a new question do not hesitate to tell me. I am new to .php and I'm trying to understand it better.

Comment: You made a very detailed reply. Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

```
if($city->originalCityname)
  $city->originalCityname .= '(Italy)';
```

If you want that `$city->originalCityname` contains Rome :

```
if(strpos($city->originalCityname,'Rome') !== false)
{
    $city->originalCityname .= ' (Italy)';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I updated the question to be more precise, could you please help me once again? Thanks!